# Moshi and retrofit2: parse content of root element

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

Since today i've received json responses like:

```
{
   "status" : "Ok",
   "otherField" : "Somevalues" 
}
```

That i map into classes like

```
data class MyResponse(
    val status : String,
    val otherField : String
)
```

Now response structure is changed in something like

```
{
   "rootElement" : {
       "status" : "Ok",
       "otherField" : "Somevalues" 
    }
}
```

There's a way to tell Moshi to parse directly content of "rootElement" whithout changing "MyResponse" structure?

Answer (score 0):

> There's a way to tell Moshi to parse directly content of "rootElement" whithout changing "MyResponse" structure?

If I understood your requirement properly, yes you can parse the content of `rootElement` without altering `MyResponse` data class. Create one more Kotlin data class like below

```
data class ResponseRoot (
    val rootElement : MyResponse
)
```

And use this `ResponseRoot` data class return type for your Retrofit Response instead of `MyResponse` class.

In your API interface just do the changes

```
@GET("url/here/")
fun fooBar(/* paramters if there any */): Call<ResponseRoot>
```